# Input image data to tensorflow placeholder

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm working with the `keras.datasets.fashion_mnist` dataset, which contains 28 x 28 grayscale images. I've built a pretty simple convolutional neural network that accepts a placeholder of images defined as:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, INPUT_CHANNELS], name='X_placeholder')
```

I'm starting out with a `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` of shape `(100, 28, 28)`. 100 here represents the batch size that I've chosen to train with.

Obviously, the dimensionality doesn't line up here. The graph I've built should work with RGB images as well, hence the INPUT_CHANNEL dimension. As expected, when I try to train, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 28, 28) for Tensor u'X_placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 28, 28, 1)'
```

Being relatively new to TF and numpy, I'm failing to see how to add in that extra dimension. Having pieced together my code from various sources, I can't say that I chose the placeholder input shape `[None, 28, 28, INPUT_CHANNELS]`, but I want to stick with it instead of trying to work around it.

## Question

How can I reshape my training data to match the expected placeholder dimensionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In numpy:**

You can use `np.newaxis`,`np.expand_dims` and `reshape()` to add dimension.

```
import numpy as np

train_data = np.random.normal(size=(100,28,28))
print(train_data.shape)

new_a = train_data[...,np.newaxis]
print(new_a.shape)
new_a = np.expand_dims(train_data,axis=-1)
print(new_a.shape)
new_a = train_data.reshape(100,28,28,1)
print(new_a.shape)

(100, 28, 28)
(100, 28, 28, 1)
(100, 28, 28, 1)
(100, 28, 28, 1)
```

**In tensorflow:**

You can use `tf.newaxis`,`tf.expand_dims` and `tf.reshape` to add dimension.

```
import tensorflow as tf

train_data = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,28,28),dtype=tf.float64)
print(train_data.shape)

new_a = train_data[...,tf.newaxis]
print(new_a.shape)
new_a = tf.reshape(train_data,shape=(-1,28,28,1))
print(new_a.shape)
new_a = tf.expand_dims(train_data,axis=-1)
print(new_a.shape)

(?, 28, 28)
(?, 28, 28, 1)
(?, 28, 28, 1)
(?, 28, 28, 1)
```